# How to config JNDI for Camel + ActiveMQ + Glassfish

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jndi, glassfish-4.1

How to config JNDI for Camel + ActiveMQ + Glassfish

That config works!

```xml
 <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://10.100.200.6:61616" />
  <property name="userName" value="admin" />
  <property name="password" value="admin" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="destResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver"/>
 <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start"
  destroy-method="stop">
  <property name="maxConnections" value="2" />
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
  <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destResolver"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="mq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
 </bean>
```

But I want to use JNDI because I don't make reference to url, user, password at the deployed xml file.

I follow the tutorial [Integrating Apache ActiveMQ with Glassfish](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-glassfish.html) and it is ok.

[image]

But when I replace `<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"` for use `<jee:jndi-lookup`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/BandMqConnFactory" />
```

I got the error:

Stracktrace:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.ra.ManagedConnectionProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:484)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:440)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:394)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:78)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createJmsException(PooledConnectionFactory.java:266)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.ra.ManagedConnectionProxy cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.wrap(PooledConnectionFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:69)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.<init>(PooledConnectionFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnectionPool(PooledConnectionFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1221)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:221)
    ... 18 more
```

`Apache Camel 2.16.x - 2.19.0`
`Glassfish 4.1 Buld 13`
`ActiveMQ  5.14.3`
`JDK 1.8`